# Could not install search plugins and theme in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, api

I have installed wordpress manually using FTP in 1and1 windows shared hosting. I could not see see the plugins when i open "Add New" plugins page as the wordpress is not able to connect to tcp://api.wordpress.org:80  from where it fetches the plugins. This also happens in the theme page.

The error i get is - "Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to tcp://api.wordpress.org:80 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ) in E:\kunden\homepages\25\d611218669\www\hosting\wp-includes\class-wp-http-streams.php on line 150"

[image]

I have already given wp-content all permissions. See attached image 
[image]

I can i solve this problem?

Comment: The problem seems about folder permission, what is the permission of wp-content folder ?

Comment: i gave the wp-content folder full permissions.

Comment: How did you manage to resolve this issue? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: @Vignesh i found out that my hosting provider company has provided so many restrictions that wordpress was not able to search plugins (actually it makes api callls to fetch plugins names, etc from main wordpress datacenter). I changed my host and this problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Windows server have these issues usually, WordPress is such a CMS where you need proper folder permission for wp-content folder. When you try to install any plugins or themes, WordPress need wp-content folder with write permission. For more details about folder permissions for WordPress, refer : https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions